# "An explicit conversion exists" - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, compiler-errors, enumerable

**The Story So Far....**

I'm learning MVC(4) at the moment. I've written my app which is full of **Controller Bloat** so i have decided to start adding Repositories/UnitOfWork/Service Layers etc.

So I have decided to create a Generic Repository to encapsulate general CRUD and record searching functionality.

**"Stop babbling, what is your problem" i hear you say**

I thought i would create a **Get** method which will take two Lambda parameters:

1. filter = Select/Deselect records logic
2. singleOrDefault = Provide one record or a default depending on parameters.

Here is the condensed **Generic Repository** code including the get method:

```
 public class GenericRepository<TEntity> :
    IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{

    internal AccountsContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;


    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public GenericRepository(AccountsContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> singleOrDefault)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null && singleOrDefault == null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (filter != null && singleOrDefault != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter)
                         .SingleOrDefault(singleOrDefault);
        }


        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Now the following compiler when i try and build this:

**Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'TEntity' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  G:\Accountable\Accountable\DataAccessLayer\GenericRepository.cs 90  30  Accountable**

The error lies on **.SingleOrDefault(singleOrDefault)** line.

For your convenience i have provided the extension method signatures im using:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);
    public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);
```

I have been staring at this for ages trying to resolve it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**FYI**

In my bloated code, i have the following type of code in my controllers which i want to replace with my repository methods, which is what im trying to replicate.

```
 LedgerCustomer LedgerCustomer = db.LedgerCustomers.Where(l => l.RecordStatus != "X").SingleOrDefault(l => l.id == id);

 CurrencyType currencyType = db.CurrencyTypes.Where(c => c.RecordStatus != "X")
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == LedgerCustomer.CurrencyTypeId);
```

**Problem is:**

A) Am i using the correct LINQ approach? The above queries from my bloated code are:

***Select Ledger customer where the RecordStatus does not equal X (Logically deleted) and the id
equals a particular id.***

Because  there should only be one record for LedgerCustomer PER id (as these are unique, I've used SingleOrDefault and Where to delselect any LedgerCustomer that is logically deleted.

B) Help with the compiler error would be helpful.

Comment: The expression `Where` and `SingleOrDefault` take are both the same kind of filter. So I don't see why you want to use both at the same time.

Comment: So what is the problem? Is it that you do not understand why it does not compile (easy to explain) or is it that you don't know how to correctly implement the method (hard to explain since it is not clear what are you trying to do)?

Comment: @CodesInChaos and Vitaliy: Firstly, thank you for your speedy reply, very much appreciated. I have edited the question. At the bottom is additonal info titles "Problem is:".

Comment: SingleOrDefault will return only single record if match found, where .Where(...) will return an list of items. You are trying to save single element TEntity to IQueryable<TEntity> thats why it throwing error. Try returning result using var result = ...SingleOrDefault... or return var result = ...Where... This might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks all a light bulb went "ping" after reading your comments! I think the main issue (apart from the glaring compiler issue!) was my understanding of SingleOrDefault. I was using Where incorrectly. I will now create 2 methods 1) "Get" will use Where(), ie a collection 2) "GetById" will use SingleOrDefault.

Comment: So what is supposed to happen if you say `Get(x => x.IsTriangular, x => x.IsYellow)`? The reason why I ask, is it's not clear how you want to use the two "predicates" (two lambda arguments) `filter` and `singleOrDefault`. - Edit: Sorry, hadn't refreshed, hadn't seen your comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies (as you expected) on the line;

```
query = query.Where(filter).SingleOrDefault(singleOrDefault);
```

`query` is an IQueryable, so using `Where(filter).SingleOrDefault(singleOrDefault)` on it is quite ok.

The problem lies in that you're trying to **assign the result of `SingleOrDefault` back to `query`**.
`SingleOrDefault` does not return an IQueryable, but instead just a single instance of `TEntity`.

Comment: Im doing to mark yours as the answer because you helped (With the commenter's above) and answered correctly concerning the compiler error #slapsmyownface#